# Red https with cross without reason (Apache + mod_ssl)

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl, mod-ssl

I just added mod_ssl with a signed certificate, but I can't figure why Google chrome is marking my connection as untrusted

screenshot:

[image: My website details]

although, another website has almost the same details, but Google chrome is not marking it as untrusted:

[image: The other website]

Can someone help me, why google chrome is marking my website as untrusted?

EDIT 1 (Adding certificate information)
[image: Certificate information]

Comment: Perhaps your site is embedding resources (scripts, stylesheets, images, …) that are not loaded via HTTPS as well? Check the browser console, that should tell you about such issues.

Comment: Check with this: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname= Most likely you have to include the full trust chain in the certificate.

Comment: @CBroe no resources are loaded externally

Comment: @AlexTartan , I added the chain in apache httpd.conf, also I can see the chain in certificate details, and in certificate status: "certificate is ok"

Comment: The difference i see between the two examples you posted is that your site is internal (not accessible from the internet). Maybe this will help http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73167/will-cas-still-validate-internal-ips-in-ssl-certs

Comment: @AlexTartan I hope you are correct, I noticed that IE and Firefox are not complaining, so the issue is related to Google chrome only.

Comment: Do you have a SHA1 certificate and does it (or any intermediate chain certificate) expire after 1/1/2017? Chrome had announced their SHA-1 deprecation plan last year. See http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html

Comment: @AnandBhat , Thank you :) , I added certificate information to that post and yes, I expires 06/21/2018 as you mentioned, I can now understand , as the other site I am comparing with, has it's certificate ends in December 2016 , please add an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Google's note on SHA-1 deprecation](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html),

> Sites with end-entity certificates that expire on or after 1 January 2017, and which include a SHA-1-based signature as part of the certificate chain, will be treated as “affirmatively insecure”. Subresources from such domain will be treated as “active mixed content”.
>
> The current visual display for “affirmatively insecure” is a lock with a red X, and a red strike-through text treatment in the URL scheme.

[image: Google Chrome showing and “affirmatively insecure” site]